# Ruby on Rails using namespaces saving record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails 5.1 to build an app, I'm trying to organize the models in namespaces but when I try to save an instance I get an error `no such table: main.users` maybe someone here can show me the way !

`app/models/frontend.rb`

```
module Frontend
  def self.table_name_prefix
   'frontend_'
  end
end
```

I'm using devise for the User migrations here's the `Frontend::User` model
`app/models/frontend/user.rb`

```
   class Frontend::User < ApplicationRecord
     # a user has many events (event creator)
     has_many :events
     # a user has and belongs to many event invitations
     has_and_belongs_to_many :event_invitations, class_name: 
     "Frontend::Event"

     # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
     # :timeoutable and :omniauthable, :confirmable
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :lockable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  end
```

`Frontend::Event` model : 
`app/models/frontend/event.rb`

```
class Frontend::Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Migration for `Frontend::Event` model :

```
class CreateFrontendEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
  create_table :frontend_events do |t|
   t.references :user, foreign_key: true
   t.string :title, :null => false
   t.text :description, :null => false
   t.string :short_description, :null => false
   t.datetime :start_date, :null => true
   t.datetime :end_date, :null => true
   t.string :address, :null => true
   t.float :latitude, :null => true
   t.float :longitude, :null => true
   t.integer :number_of_guest, :null => true
   t.boolean :published, default: false
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

In rails console :

I can create a user

```
u = Frontend::User.create(email: "user@user.com", password: "secret")
```

I can use the build method with the `has_many :events` relationship

```
e = u.events.build

 <Frontend::Event id: nil, user_id: 1, title: nil, description: 
 nil, short_description: nil, start_date: nil, end_date: nil, address: 
 nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, number_of_guest: nil, published: 
 false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

The problem occurs when trying to save a record `e.save`

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: 
main.users: INSERT INTO "frontend_events" ("user_id", 
"created_at","updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some problems with the rails conventions. As far as I know you should name the join table in a special way.

You can look the rails guides, specially in the section for [creating join tables for has and belongs to many associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#creating-join-tables-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations).

Following the guide I was able build more less what you are building, but without devise.

In the example I have this three migrations...

```
class CreateFrontendUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :frontend_users do |t|
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateFrontendEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :frontend_events do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateFrontendEventsUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :frontend_events_users, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :event_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end

    add_index :frontend_events_users, :event_id
    add_index :frontend_events_users, :user_id
  end
end
```

And this two models...

```
class Frontend::Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Frontend::User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end
```

And with that in the rails console I was able to do...

```
user = Frontend::User.create(email: "asdf")
event = user.events.create(name: "event1")
user.events # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Frontend::Event id: 1, name: "event1", created_at: "...", updated_at: "...">]>
event.users # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Frontend::User id: 1, email: "asdf", created_at: "...", updated_at: "...">]>
```

**Consider use has_many through associations**

If you want to have more control over the joining table records, is a common practice to use "has many" through associations. If you have not heard about about them you can also look at the guides in the section [The has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

You can also recreate the example changing the `CreateFrontendEventsUsersJoinTable` migration for...

```
class CreateFrontendEventInvitations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :frontend_event_invitations do |t|
      t.integer :event_id
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :frontend_event_invitations, :event_id
    add_index :frontend_event_invitations, :user_id
  end
end
```

And now your models would be like...

```
class Frontend::Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :event_invitations
  has_many :users, through: :event_invitations
end

class Frontend::User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :event_invitations
  has_many :events, through: :event_invitations
end

class Frontend::EventInvitation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

I almos always prefer to use this kind of association instead of the `has_many_and_belongs_to` association. But you can decide which is better for you =)

Sometimes is hard to know all the rails conventions, even if you have been working with Rails several years =S ... but the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) and http://api.rubyonrails.org/ help a lot!

I hope it helps =)

Comment: Sure did thanks it worked up a point but it was making the job harder I'm new at programing, I will stick to conventions rather than configuration but I think it will be usefull for me to learn so I have this on the side so I can learn how to use namespace correctly in a rails app. Thanks again for yout time to help.

Comment: I added an example using "has_many :through" association. If you are new in the Rails world, maybe you can read about it, and see if is better for your use case =)